# Shuffle column values per row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing a Multiple-Choice Exam Generator using C#.NET. Every time a report is made, questions are picked randomly in the database and choices are shuffled randomly. I can do the random questions part, but i can't do the shuffling of choices.

I have a table with a row like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|question|answer|distractor1|distractor2|distractor3|
|q1      |ansq1 |d1q1       |d2q1       |d2q1       |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

What I would like to happen is to shuffle the values of column **answer**, **distractor1**, and **distractor3**. For example:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
|question|answer|distractor1|distractor2|distractor3|
|q1      |d3q1  |d2q1        |d1q1       |ansq1     |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

is this possible using SQL queries?

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: @HasanAlizada I use MS SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Why does the answer change from `ansq1` to `d3q1`  for the same question? . Answer should always be the same no?

Comment: @KaushikNayak no because i used parameters in RDLC for the choices. the order is in:

A. Answer
B. Distractor 1
C. Distractor 2
D. Distractor 3

I'll have to re-shuffle or else the answer would always be A from all questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one trick using `Dynamic Sql`

```
WHILE 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @answer SYSNAME = (SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_NAME
            FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
            WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ( 'question', 'answer')
            ORDER  BY Newid())
        DECLARE @distractor1 SYSNAME = (SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_NAME
            FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
            WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ( 'question', @answer, 'distractor1' )
            ORDER  BY Newid())
        DECLARE @distractor2 SYSNAME = (SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_NAME
            FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
            WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ( 'question', @answer, 'distractor2', @distractor1 )
            ORDER  BY Newid())
        DECLARE @distractor3 SYSNAME = (SELECT TOP 1 COLUMN_NAME
            FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns
            WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ( 'question', @answer, 'distractor3', @distractor2, @distractor1 )
            ORDER  BY Newid())

        IF @distractor1 IS NOT NULL
            AND @distractor2 IS NOT NULL
            AND @distractor3 IS NOT NULL
            AND @answer IS NOT NULL
        BREAK
    END
--select @distractor1,@distractor2,@distractor3
exec( 'update yourtable set answer = '+@answer+', distractor1 = '+@distractor1+', distractor2 = '+@distractor2+', distractor3 = '+@distractor3)

select * from yourtable
```

Comment: I think the query executes forever... why is that? I don't have many records on my database though

Comment: @Chanchan - While Loop will execute untill all the variables are not null.. Make sure you replace the `yourtable` with your original table name..

Comment: oh i forgot to change 'yourtable' to my table name. yikes

Comment: hey it works but some of the columns are affected... there are exactly 20 columns but i just needed the columns **answer**, **distractor1**, **distractor2**, and **distractor3** to be shuffled

Comment: @Chanchan - Simple add a condition in `where` clause.. `COLUMN_NAME  in ('answer','distractor1','distractor2','distractor3 ')` in all the four select queries inside while loop

Comment: Also, when having 2 or more rows, they have the same pattern. for example:

Row1: q1 | d1q1 | d2q1 | ansq1 |

Row2: q2 | d1q2 | d2q2 | ansq2 |

and the pattern goes on

Comment: @Chanchan - You can't keep changing/adding requirement just like that.. Please ask a new question